# Geometric Brownian Motion; Simulation of Stock Price

Tags: c++, algorithm, montecarlo

I made a GBM function in C++ and I believe I am getting too much of a range of stock prices when I start with an initial price of 100 the output can be from [50,400]. I am not sure what I am doing wrong in my code, I am guessing there is something wrong with the way I seed the random standard normal numbers. Please have a look at the function and let me know if there is anything I shold modify or change.

Here is the function:

```
std::vector<double> GBM(const int M, const int N, const double T, const double r, const double q, const double sigma, const double S0){
    double dt =  T/N;
    std::vector<double> Z;
    std::vector<double> S;
    S.push_back(S0);
    std::mt19937 e2(time(0));
    std::normal_distribution<double> dist(0.0, 1.0);
    for(int i = 0; i < M; i++){
        Z.push_back(dist(e2));
    }
    double drift  = exp(dt*((r - q)-0.5*sigma*sigma));
    double vol = sqrt(sigma*sigma*dt);
    for(int i = 1; i < M; i++){
        S.push_back(S[i-1] * drift * exp(vol*Z[i]));
    }
    return S;
}
```

Here is the main.cpp file that utilizes the function above:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "LSM.h"
#include <cmath>
#include <ctime>
#include <Eigen/Core>
#include <Eigen/SVD>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <random>

std::vector<double> GBM(const int M, const int N, const double T, const double r, const double q, const double sigma, const double S0);

int main(){
    const double r = 0.04;          // Riskless interest rate
    const double q = 0.0;           // Divident yield
    const double sigma = 0.20;      // Volatility of stock
    const double T = 1;             // Time (expiry)
    const int N = 1000;             // Number of time steps
    const double K = 100.0;         // Strike price
    const double S0 = 100.0;        // Initial stock price
    const int M = 10000;                // Number of paths
    const int R = 2;                // Choice of basis for Laguerre polynomial

    //LSM Option_value(r,q,sigma,T,N,K,S0,M,R);

    std::vector<double> s = GBM(M,N,T,r,q,sigma,S0);
    for(int i = 0; i < M; i++){
        std::cout << s[i] << std::endl;
    }



    return 0;
}
```

A typical output that one should get starting with an initial stock price of 100 is below:

```
  153.5093
  132.0190
   96.2550
  106.5196
   58.8447
  135.3935
  107.1194
  101.2022
  134.2812
   82.2146
   87.9162
   74.9333
   88.9137
  207.5150
  123.7893
   95.8526
  120.0831
   96.3990
  103.3806
  113.8258
  100.6409
   92.0724
   81.1704
  121.9925
  114.3798
  117.8366
   86.1070
   74.4885
   82.6013
   78.0202
   97.0586
  119.7626
   89.0520
   72.2328
   92.1998
   84.7180
  138.9160
   91.0091
  105.2096
   91.3323
   79.0289
  115.9377
   75.4887
  123.2049
  101.1904
   95.9454
   82.4181
  108.8314
  123.0198
   76.8494
   94.8827
  149.5911
   95.6969
  143.3498
   87.0939
   77.3033
  105.8185
  122.3455
   79.8208
  112.9913
  120.1649
  131.3052
  136.8246
   96.5455
  109.0187
   87.1363
  103.1835
  106.3896
  143.9496
  119.1357
   99.9114
  111.1409
   79.0563
  147.1506
  105.7851
   99.7089
  117.8770
   99.7602
   73.1796
  125.8698
  109.4367
  135.5020
   88.1979
  129.8502
  121.1233
   76.7520
   86.5296
  118.6721
   83.2511
  116.3950
   99.8795
   70.6895
   64.9578
  111.4750
  102.6343
   82.8765
   90.3479
  106.8873
  106.3850
  119.3399
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.

Comment: @Prune I am not familiar with posting on this site, what is MCVE code?

Comment: Follow the link in my comment.  Your update is good; just supply a trivial main program to produce this output, and then make it clear what you *wanted* for output, in contrast to what you *did* get.

Comment: @Prune Okay will do

Comment: From the comments behind the constants, you want to simulate 10000 paths of an integration from 0 to 1 using 1000 subdivision steps, i.e., a step size of `0.001`. What you are doing is integrating one path over 10000 steps of step size 0.001, that is, from 0 to 10. Please correct your code to reflect your initial intentions.

Comment: I rewrite it according to wiki version https://pastebin.com/6bi8zZCs. May it helps. You need to change your M back to 10000

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Function GBM should simulate 1 path every time. So no need to supply M. And the path length is, in your code, defined by N instead of M.

If you implement this change, GBM return the whole simulated path. 
Then you need to call GBM M times in order to calculate all the simulations.

Also there is no need to store all the random numbers generated.

Based on your sample, something like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <random>

// Random generator initialize (only once).
static std::mt19937 rng(time(0)); 

std::vector<double> GBM(const int N, const double T, const double r,
        const double q, const double sigma, const double S0)
{
    double dt =  T/N;
    std::vector<double> S;
    S.push_back(S0);
    std::normal_distribution<double> dist(0.0, 1.0);
    double drift  = exp(dt*((r - q)-0.5*sigma*sigma));
    double vol = sqrt(sigma*sigma*dt);
    for(int i = 1; i < N; i++){
        double Z = dist(rng);
        S.push_back(S[i-1] * drift * exp(vol*Z));
    }
    return S;
}

int main(){
    const double r = 0.04;          // Riskless interest rate
    const double q = 0.0;           // Divident yield
    const double sigma = 0.20;      // Volatility of stock
    const double T = 1;             // Time (expiry)
    const int N = 1000;             // Number of time steps
    const double S0 = 100.0;        // Initial stock price
    const int M = 100;              // Number of paths

    for (int sindx = 0; sindx < M; sindx++)
    {
        std::vector<double> s = GBM(N,T,r,q,sigma,S0);

        std::cout << "Simulation " << sindx << ": "
            << s[0] << ", " << s[1] << " ... " << s[N-2] << ", " << s[N-1]
            << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you provide working C++ code, then I will happily reward the points

Answer (score 1):

From the comments behind the constants, you want to simulate 10000 paths of an integration from 0 to 1 using 1000 subdivision steps, i.e., a step size of 0.001.

What you are doing is integrating one path over 10000 steps of step size 0.001, that is, from 0 to 10.

If you do this correctly, the result should look like a list of

```
S0 * exp( ((r-q)-0.5*sigma*sigma)*T + sigma*sqrt(T)*Z[i] )
```

as the value of the GBM at time `T` only depends on `W(T)` which is distributed as `N(0,T)` or `sqrt(T)*N(0,1)`.

Comment: Could you provide a bit more information in regards to simulating 10000 paths of an integration from 0 to 1 using 1000 subdivision steps? I may be mistaken but it seems like I need to use two for loops?

Comment: Do you need the intermediate values? Usually for something like american options. If only the price distribution at T=1 is of interest, you can just sample as in the second part. -- Else you need nested loops, one for 1..M and the inner for 1..N or vice versa, and a 2-dimensional array to hold the results.

Comment: Well just starting with an initial value of 100, I need to generate M stock paths. So it seems I need a matrix instead of just a vector, I was trying to avoid that in order to make things run faster

Comment: I made a bounty if you could provide some workable code I would be happy to give you the 100 points